# How to change title on Magento Review Page?

Tags: magento

For example, I need to add two words "Reviews for:" before "Product name" in Reviews page title
How to? Can't find the way
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using observer for **review_controller_product_init_after** event.
In observer you can use following method:

```
$this->getControllerAction()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle(...)
```